# how to use the procedure that I made in other acees datebase

Tags: ms-access, module, vba

how to use the procedure that I made for one datebase, if you want to always run when I open access.
I create two module . and i want to run them always when i open access.Their task  is to open a table that I want. What i need doing? in Excell record macro, but in access?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly...  You want to use code/table from another database in every database you open?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot record macros in MS Access, but you can create macros, however, if all you want to do is to edit a table, first create the form using the form wizard, a datasheet will probably suit, and next choose File->Options, Current Database, Display Form and select the form you just created from the dropdown list (Access 2010/2007).

You can add a reference to a database in the same way you would add any other reference (from the code window, select tools, references, browse). Once you have the reference, you can run any code in that database, however, for simplicity, ensure you have given unique names to your modules and procedures to avoid name conflicts.

Once you have done this, create a form that calls the code as you would call any code from a command button.

Comment: ok, but i dont have table when i open acccess.My vba module import some table from my folder. i want something that run my vba procedure , some button or macro alwayse visibly for other users which  needs to open specified (condition in vba code) table...  then maniluplate with her. An easier way NOT to go:Datebase tools,Visal Basic,clik on some module and then Run.And most importantly, CALL that module, procedure alwayse in other database